# Change geoserver password from CLI

Tags: geoserver

I'm configuring a server with several services and I want to know if is possible to change default Geoserver username/password using CLI, using `configuration file/environment variables/CLI command/whatever`, without having to log in manually and change it using the GUI.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the cli but you should be able to do everything you want using the geoserver rest API (you can access it to : localhost:8080/geoserver/rest ).

Have a look for user management : http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html

Maybe you can have a script which will take you configuration and trigger some curl call on the API so your Geoserver will be all set up.